# How to stream videos using HTML5 and Javascript

Tags: javascript, html5-video

I want to make a site that streams live media over the net incorporating a web player built in HMTL5. I have read about the Microsoft's Media Streaming Platform and SWf of Microsoftfor streaming media but all of it went over the head.
Is there any one true way of streaming videos without using any plugins like Flash but in simple HTML5 and JS.
I have asked this question a lot of time here before but every time it was unanswered. Please help me.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try http://www.videojs.com/ It's pretty easy to implement.

Comment: Video js is just a web player, the video player that I am using is videojs

Comment: This answer provides no useful content and lacks research.

Comment: Anuj asking about something to replace flash. In a way that library solve it. If he asking about streaming platform e2e I will answer differently